# emit to all after receiving a broadcast

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I've got a little app that generates a code and stores it in mongodb(My chrome browser). Another user(My firefox browser) enters the given code and broadcasts it to let my chrome know that he's there.

Now i want my chrome browser to emit an agreement to itself and my firefox browser so they both get parsed by the same function the moment the agreement is emitted.

The point however is that i only get 1 console log in my terminal which leads me to think that only Chrome(or Firefox, which i doubt) is listening to the emit.

Can anyone take a look why not both browsers receive the 'agreement' emit?

My app.js: (The on connection part)

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('code_game', function (data) {
        if (codeToUse == data.code) {
            //The receiving end received the proper code from the sending end
            console.log(data.secondUser + ' is verbonden via de code: ' + data.code);
            //Emit to all parties to let everyone know there's a connection
            socket.emit('agreement', { 
                userOne: {
                    name: 'Timen',
                    code: codeToUse
                },
                userTwo: {
                    name: data.secondUser,
                    code: data.code
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And the JS file being called in my view: (sendToFirstUser is Firefox in this case)

```
var receivingUsersCode = false;
var receivingUsersName = false;
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

socket.on('agreement', function (data) {
    console.log("hooray");
});

function setReceivingData(code, username) {
    receivingUsersCode = code;
    receivingUsersName = username;
    ding = 'drie';
    $('#new_game').css('display', 'block');
    $('.theCode').html(receivingUsersCode);


}

function sendToFirstUser(code, username) {
    socket.emit('code_game', { code: code, secondUser: username});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking.  But it seems to me like you're asking why both your Chrome and Firefox browser aren't emitting an 'agreement' event.  If that's it, I think you've answered your own question:

> "Another user(My firefox browser) enters the given code and broadcasts it to let my chrome know that he's there."

```
//Starts broadcasting to other clients
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('code_game', { code: req.body.code, secondUser: req.body.secondUser});
});
```

Your firefox browser only emits to other clients (your chrome browser) through socket.broadcast.emit.  So, only the chrome browser receives the 'code_game' event on the browser side.  But in your browser side code, the client emits the 'agreement' event when it receives the 'code_game' event:

```
socket.on('code_game', function (data) {
    if (receivingUsersCode == data.code) {
        console.log(data.secondUser + ' is is connected via code: ' + data.code);
        listenForMutualConnection();
        socket.emit('agreement', { 
            userOne: {
                name: receivingUsersName,
                code: receivingUsersCode
                },
            userTwo: {
                name: data.secondUser,
                code: data.code
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Since only the chrome browser is receiving the 'code_game' event, it's also the only one emitting the 'agreement' event.

Comment: I want both parties to end up in agreement so i can redirect both parties to do X. I've managed to get my firefox to emit to code_game and the code_game method is now emitting back to firefox. How can i get that code_game method to send it to both parties? I've updated my code above.

Comment: Aaaaannndd fixed. I should've emitted through `io.socket` instead of `socket` in my code_game method